# Laravel 4: When to use static methods?

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm new to Laravel 4 and I wonder when to use static methods and when to use custom attribute accessors. This might be a philosophical question, but I'd like to learn more about the pros and cons of both approaches.

**Example 1:**

I have the following relationship: a user has many collections. Now, I can do this:

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    ....
    public function collections() {
        return $this->hasMany('Collection')->orderBy('order_nr', 'ASC');
    }
}
```

Since I'm working a lot with the current user that's logged in, I'd use this like so in a Controller or Template:

```
$collections = Auth::user()->collections()->get();
```

However, I could also take the entire different route and call this via a static method of my `Collection` class:

```
class Collection extends Eloquent { 
    public function scopeOfUser($query, $user_id) {
        return $query->where('user_id', '=', $user_id)->orderBy('order_nr', 'ASC');
    }
}
```

Then, I'd get all collections of a user like so:

```
$collections = Collection::ofUser(Auth::id())->get();
```

**Example 2:**

I store user settings in a key-value table called `UserSettings`. Thus, my user has a one to many relationship to UserSetting. If I want to check upon some attributes, I can go two ways again:

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    public function getHasFullAccountAttribute() {
        return $this->hasMany('UserSetting')->whereKey('account_type')->whereValue('full')->count() > 0;
    }
}
```

The function call would be:

```
Auth::user()->has_full_account;
```

Other way is a static function that uses the DB:

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    public static function hasFullAccount($user_id) {
        return DB::table('users')
            ->join('user_settings', 'users.id', '=', 'user_settings.user_id')
            ->where('user_settings.key', '=', 'account_type')
            ->where('user_settings.value', '=', 'full')
            ->where('users.id', '=', $user_id)
            ->count() > 0;
    }
}
```

And the call is then:

```
User::hasFullAccount(Auth::id());
```

So, I guess both ways are legitimate, both ways yield the correct results, but when do you use the model class in a static way and when do you usually operate on the object itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you'd want the static when you don't already have a model, and the non-static when you have a model.

For example:

```
// we don't already have a user model here
User::hasFullAccount(12345);

// we have user models here
foreach($users as $user) {
   $user->hasFullAccount;
}
```